# Unit testing Void method which calls another void, starts Task()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2013

I'm looking for some advice on writing some unit tests for the code below. Implementation aside (it's not my code, but I've been tasked to retroactively write some tests for it) could someone suggest how I might test this? I'm not using nUnit or a similar framework; I am using the testing tools built into Visual Studio.

I'm fairly new to writing unit tests, but I imagine I should at least test the following:

- Valid response passed into `SaveFormBrokerResponse()` method
- Test for valid exceptions thrown by the `catch()`
- Testing the started `Task`, but not sure how to do this

I've stripped just a bit out of this function, mostly to do with instantiation and population of some objects:

```
public void SaveResponse(IForm form, bool isLive, HttpRequestBase request)
{
    try
    {
        var response = new FormBrokerResponses();
        // Initialize some vars on response

        using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(FormKeyValue[]));
            serializer.WriteObject(memory, request.Form.AllKeys.Select(r => new FormKeyValue(r, request.Form[r])).ToArray());
            memory.Flush();
            memory.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            response.Values = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memory.ToArray());
        }

        _dataHandler.SaveFormBrokerResponses(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("boom explosions");
    }

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DispatchFormResponseViaEmail(form, isLive, request.Form.AllKeys.ToDictionary(r => r, r => (object)request.Form[r])));
}
```

I realize that testing `void` implementations is tricky and questionable and that there are some integration test concerns here, but that said I can't (currently) change the implementation and need to write tests for what I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are allowed to make slight modifications to the code I would do the following which is just a small change anyway :

```
public void SaveResponse(IForm form, bool isLive, HttpRequestBase request)
{
    try
    {
        var response = new FormBrokerResponses();
        // Initialize some vars on response

        using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(FormKeyValue[]));
            serializer.WriteObject(memory, request.Form.AllKeys.Select(r => new FormKeyValue(r, request.Form[r])).ToArray());
            memory.Flush();
            memory.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            response.Values = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memory.ToArray());
        }

        _dataHandler.SaveFormBrokerResponses(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("boom explosions");
    }

    Dispatch(form,isLive,request);
}

virtual void Dispatch(IForm form, bool isLive, HttpRequestBase request){
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DispatchFormResponseViaEmail(form, isLive, request.Form.AllKeys.ToDictionary(r => r, r => (object)request.Form[r])));
}
```

I don't know what this class is named so suppose the class is named DutClass, you can now derive a different implementation of that class as following:

```
public class UnitTestClass : DutClass{
    override Dispatch(){
        //don't do anything or set a state variable that this method was called
    }
}
```

Then instead of testing the DutClass you test the UnitTextClass which has a different implementation of the Dispatch method and does not start a Task at all. You can then test that in fact this method was called, test for the exceptions and so on.

Comment: Ahh, interesting. So in effect you're creating a mock object which inherits from the original in all ways except for the fact that you've overridden the `Dispatch()` method, which you can then verify its execution?

Comment: I'm curious, if the `DispatchFormResponseViaEmail()` method is a private method in that same class, is it possible to somehow still do something like this but override that private method only, and test like that?

Comment: private methods can also be virtual, so the trick itself works, yes. But the problem will be that you don't have control over when it finishes, probably when the unit test itself is already complete and thus if you check a state variable checking if the method ran yes or no, it will give a failing test. Give it a try, I learn a lot by attempting stuff that eventually does not always work.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer because it most closely answers the question. Thanks for the advice on the refactoring; very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  You've created a method that fires off an asynchronous operation and then doesn't expose any means of observing the completion/results of that operation to the caller.  There are lots of ways of doing this (returning a task, accepting a callback, an event, etc.) but you need to do *something* for the caller to be able to observe the results of the asynchronous operation.  If the method doesn't expose anything, then there is nothing that the caller can reliably do.

Comment: Hah, well then, thanks for clarifying that. Makes perfect sense. I guess given that, is there a way that I can test the way the task is called? In other words, would there be a way to test that the task is started with parameter that meet certain expectations? I am probably asking a bit much from the testing framework but sort of learning what options are available. Thank you!

Comment: @trnelson If you expose that information to the caller of the method, by returning that info, using a callback, etc, then yes.  Anything else would be *super* fragile, relying on internal implementation details subject to change, and as a result a failed test would be far more likely to be a false indication of a problem.

Comment: Definitely makes sense. Looking a bit deeper, the task method `DispatchFormResponseViaEmail` is also a `void` which calls a `Trace.TraceError()` when it fails. I guess what it boils down to is that this method is called with the general assumption that it will pass, but failure just ends up in a log message to be later diagnosed. And that seems to leave very little for testing.